# Was Data's speed affected by the polywater intoxication?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

At the end of the episode, "The Naked Now," Data moves quickly in order to replace the removed isolinear chips. The Enterprise is in the path of a stellar core fragment and needs to move to avoid being blown to smithereens.

For some strange reason, Data was infected by the polywater. Is it reasonable to believe that his replacing of the isolinear chips was slowed due to this? He seems fairly competent while replacing the chips, so I'm uncertain.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is it you are seeking to be clarified?

Comment: I don't see how it's unclear. I'm asking if the polywater intoxication slowed Data's replacing of the isolinear chips.

Comment: That isn't what you wrote...

Comment: "Was Data's speed affected by the polywater intoxication?" I then gave background information, followed by a question which is supposed to prompt the person to think: if it's reasonable that Data's reaction time was slowed due to the polywater intoxication, then by all means, expound on it. If it's not reasonable, give your reasoning for that, too. Again, I'm not really sure what you find so difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Data was clearly affected by the polywater intoxication.

As portrayed in the episode the intoxication seemed to spread by contact, and Data after a "fully functional" encounter with an infected Yar, shows clear signs of infection in his unusual behavior on the bridge and in his discussion with captain Picard.

While reinstalling the isolinear chips in engineering Data seemed to be enjoying it, and he actually was not interested until Wesley proposed it as a kind of game shuffling the chips like cards.  It seems as if the polywater intoxication only affected judgement and behavior, but not ability, as Data was quite adept at quickly reinstalling the chips.

I think the most telling is that after Dr. Crusher perfected an antidote, Picard took a hypospray to engineering and Data was one of the first to be inoculated.

In general, after recently re-watching the first season, Data is initially treated as a much more biological artificial being, often shown in sick bay being examined and diagnosed by Dr. Crusher.  So his being affected by the polywater is not out of character with the early treatment of Data in the TNG series.